# Javascript wont run in Google App Script HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm running a Javascript in my html and using google app script.

I try to make a table using Javascript but it seems the Javascript isn't working at all.

I even temporarily move the script into the html and it still not working at all.

Here's my code:

**Code.gs**

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1btr_VWS4A6rjyImN9IBxMJiAEfSOThB96Zy37dafGfo/edit#gid=0" ;

function doGet() {
 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('home').evaluate();
}
 
//GET DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEET AND RETURN AS AN ARRAY
function getData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var Data =ws.getDataRange().getValues();
  console.log(Data);
  return Data;
}
 
// INCLUDE JAVASCRIPT AND CSS FILES
function include(filename) { 
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!--INCLUDE REQUIRED EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT AND CSS LIBRARIES-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
 
    <?!= include('Javascript'); ?> 
    
  </head>
 
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered md-6">
         <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Test 1<th>
            <th>Test 2<th>
            <th>Test 3<th>
          </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="data-table">

        </tbody>   
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
      
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script >

      var data = [
        [1,2,3]
        [a,b,c]
      ];
      
      
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
        var tbody = document.getElementById("data-table");

        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        var col1 = document.createElement("td");
        col1.textContent = "Test";
        row.appendChild (col1);
        tbody.appendChild(row);
      });
</script >
```

I want to fill the column [in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMGxK.png) with "Test" in one of the column, but no matter what i do the javascript wont run/dont return anything to the html.

also yes, im following certain tutorial on youtube but it wont works when i try even the coding 100% same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="yourscript.js"></script>
```

Add above insted of include tag if you are using external file for js
else put script inside html or head